# Excel - How do you compare on two separate columns for matching name and then print the biggest value in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So my question in more detail is this

Column A - Organization name(Jeffs Pizza) {Dons burgers}

Column B - New Money amount  ?? this is what is need ??

Column C - Organization name(Jeffs Pizza, Jeffs Pizza, Jeffs Pizza){Dons burgers, Dons burgers, Dons burgers}

Column D- Amount each month ( 1,000, 250,000, 65,000) {75,000, 45,000, 35,000}

Now the spreadsheet I have includes way more data than this~1000 items in each and it's too much to do by hand, this is just an example.
I need to compare column A with column C then once it matches search Column D for the biggest value for the matching name.

Now In my spread sheet, the names do not match exactly. So I just need the search to include the main name.
For example, I may have Dons burgers inc., Dons burgers LLC and they still need to be searched as if they are just Dons burgers.

Thank you for all your help I truly appreciate it.

Comment: To get an answer, you really should draw a Table showing what you want specfically.

Answer (score 0):

You have three important elements here. One is a way to identify the data you need the `MAX()` value from, one is to isolate that data so `MAX()` can do its magic, and one is that there is something unusual about how you will do the first one.

So, the second one:  there is a function called `FILTER()` that will isolate data the way you need. It can give you cells filled with the data if that would suit your need of the day, though it wouldn't be one's first choice here, or it can just give that output to the formula to work on which is what you WILL do here. Basically, it can look at your data and find all the matches in Column C for whatever you present it in Column A. After it finds those matches, it can return information from any matching column you specify. Or columns, plural. Great for what you want to do as other lookup functions like to return a single value, not a bunch of them.

That's straightforward. How do you identify the good matches though? Usually in an Excel function, when you have a criteria parameter for matching something, you can use wildcards. Each function is a little different about how to do that but you can use them. `FILTER()` does not seem to like wildcards though. However, it will use a form one doesn't usually think of and that is comparing strings in a greater than or less than kind of way, like you'd naturally do with numbers, but just don't think of at all for strings. So you will do that to make `FILTER()` work.

That will return the Column D values (again, to cells if you wished, but in this case, to the formula) for the Column C matches. Then you will use the `MAX()` function to pick the largest of those Column D matches:

```
=MAX( FILTER($D$2:$D$1001, $C$2:$C$1001>=A1) )
```

So, that is the formula to use. But there is now one other concern you should consider. And VERY carefully:

What if "Dons Burger" is in Column C as "Don's Burger"? Then this won't work. As you have specified the problem, the assumption is that Column C WILL always start off with what's in Column A, so if 10 letters are in the Column A value, the first 10 letters of ALL the target entries in Column C will start with those 10 letters. But... what if that 4th letter is an apostrophe? Then it all fails.

Maybe not a problem, but maybe something to examine before relying on the results!

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't be a whole answer, but might be a helpful starting point. You probably need to add some helper columns to hold a "clean" version of column A, and a "clean" version of column C, then compare those.
There are a couple of ways you could approach this:

1. use lookups

Take a copy of all possible values in columns A and C, paste them as a single list somewhere and remove duplicates. For every entry, in the next column put what that really means. Eg Dons Burger Joint > Dons Burgers; Donnie's Burgers > Dons Burgers; Dan's Burgers > Dons Burgers.
This second column should have lots of duplicates, and should have no values which are different but refer to the same thing.
For columns A and C, in two new columns use a lookup to find the value A|C holds and return the corresponding "correct" value. For column C you will need to do some parsing with LEFT or MID and FIND to get the bit of text between the ( and the first comma before you look it up. Then compare these to see which ones match.

2. Use "cleaning" functions to get rid of extraneous information. Nest SUBSTITUTE functions lots of times to remove things like " LLC" and " Inc", and all punctuation marks then TRIM to get a "stripped down" version of the name. As long as you don't have a customer called Jeff's Pizza and another called Jeffs P'izza you should be fine
3. Potentially do 2, but maybe less of it, then use that to do a lookup as in 1.

When you get new data, you might need to add more rows to the lookup table for all the new and creative ways people have entered data this time round, and just build that up over time. (use your lookups to throw meaningful message out if a value is not found in your table).